# How do you keep the order using SELECT WHERE IN()?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, sql-order-by

Is there a way to keep the order when using SELECT WHERE IN()? For example, using the following query:

```
SELECT id FROM data_table WHERE id IN(56,55,54,1,7);
```

The results will come back using the default order by id. 1,7,54,55,56

When I want to keep the order used in the IN: 56,55,54,1,7

Is there a quick way to do this in MySQL or will I be forced to order it after in code?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(id, '56,55,54,1,7')
```

Comment: One question, this causes the query to use a filesort. Should I be concerned with performance using this method? Or is this a question for a different thread?

Comment: @Pepper: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/03/05/what-does-using-filesort-mean-in-mysql/

Comment: Anything like this in Postgres?

Comment: @Dziamid: Not natively that I'm aware of, but you can [do it in a function of your own](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2009-12/msg00033.php)

Comment: what if I am using mysql. the FIND_IN_SET didnt work for me.

Comment: It's worth noting that any linebreak or space in the string will cause unexpected results. In other words, this will break: `'56,55, 54,1,7'`  That aside, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use FIELD:

```
ORDER BY FIELD(id, '56,55,54,1,7')
```

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field
- http://ivanjovanovic.com/2008/04/01/preserving-ordering-with-where-in-clause-in-mysql/

Comment: this is not working as expected the order of the passed list is not respected in case the list has mixed order ( not all crescent or descrescent ), `FIND_IN_SET` instead respect the exact order of the list

Comment: Confirmed, this does not keep the order.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a UNION, that might return the order the same way.

BUT:

Why not just have your application reorder the results when it receives them, rather than forcing the DB to do it?

Comment: The DB will scale the ordering far better than your application ever could.  10 records is nothing - what if the result set is 10,000, or millions?