# I don't want MySQL to sort the results found

Tags: php, mysql

Currently, I'm retrieving some data from a MySQL database table, but the problem is every time the query executed, by default MySQL sort the result according to automatic-generated-id which is field name [id]. I don't want to be sorted. In my case:

```
$keys = array(4, 1, 7, 8, 2, 5, 6);
$strKeys = implode(',', $keys);
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id in('.$strKeys.')');
```

I want the result in order from what the $keys looks like: 4, 1, 7, 8, 2, 5, 6
BUT indeed, the result comes out in sorted order by [id]: 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

How to get the result and display as in order from the $keys.

Comment: The easiest thing to do will be to just resort the array or  (probably best) index it by id and then use $keys to loop through it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you keep the order using SELECT WHERE IN()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813884/how-do-you-keep-the-order-using-select-where-in)

Comment: Wow!  Never knew that function exists.  >.<

Comment: Thanks to @OMG Ponies, Corbin, , looyao, problem solved now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id in (4, 1, 7, 8, 2, 5, 6) order by find_in_set(id, '4, 1, 7, 8, 2, 5, 6');
```

Comment: Yes, that works! Pretty much thanks. I've never known this before.