# Show multiple rows in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

I had a table like this

```
id   |   name 
------------------
1    |   SAM1
2    |   SAM2
1    |   SAM1
3    |   SAM3
7    |   SAM7
6    |   SAM6
```

I need to show the results using this query

```
SELECT name,id FROM tblnameWHERE id IN (1,2,7,6,1)
```

and getting the following result

```
id   |   name 
------------------
1    |   SAM1
2    |   SAM2
7    |   SAM7
6    |   SAM6
```

My problem is this skipped last id , ie 1 . I need something like this

```
id   |   name 
------------------
1    |   SAM1
2    |   SAM2
7    |   SAM7
6    |   SAM6
1    |   SAM1
```

With out using the loop query ( like follows ) any other method for doing this ?

```
$ids=array(1,2,7,6,1);
$i=0;
foreach($ids as $id){

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE id=$id");
// Store value to array 

}
```

Please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you keep the order using SELECT WHERE IN()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813884/how-do-you-keep-the-order-using-select-where-in)

Comment: When I create a table without a primary key `CREATE TABLE bar (id INT, name VARCHAR(10))` and insert your data and perform your query, I get all 5 rows back out. Are you only getting 4 rows out? Do you have some sort of key on your table preventing duplicates?

Comment: thanks for the reply and ... I am using the id as the primary key of my table ... Still getting only 4

Comment: Then that is the problem. A primary key *must* be unique, and you have two rows with value 1, which is not possible.

Comment: check `select *` the second entry with id 1 might not have gotten inserted ,because primary key should be unique.

Comment: @OMGPonies reading the ans of the "possible duplicate", it's about ordering, isn't it? so, not a duplicate at all. Moreover, not useful to solve the OP problem, unless find_in_set can contain duplicate "id" that will result in duplicate rows (but the word "set" suggests me duplicate elements will be handled as single)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query

```
SELECT name,id FROM tblname WHERE id IN (1,2,7,6);
```

should show duplicate rows; e.g. if there are *really* in the table two distinct rows with the very same id, then the query will show them (since there's no DISTINCT keyword).

Instead, if you want to create duplicate lines starting from a table containing single lines, you have to join your table with a table having repeated 1 (in your case); another way could be to use union like this:

```
SELECT  name, id FROM tblname WHERE id IN (1,2,7,6)
  UNION ALL
SELECT name, id FROM tblname WHERE id = 1;
```

**Edit**

Since your id is a primary key, it will be unique, hence the "problem" you're experiencing. If you want to allow duplicate rows on insert, remove the primary key. If you need it, consider the possible solutions suggested above.

Comment: UNION is a bad choice on this case

Comment: I have not written "it is a good choice". I've just listed a choice.

Comment: (which, btw, solved the problem without arguing on how the table was created or how the table should be)

Answer (score 1):

you must make ids unique, you have same id for different rows, therefore you can't get both rows at the same time.

Comment: thanks for the reply and thats my primary key of my table. any method for solving the issue ?

Comment: primary keys must be unique, so you must change the ids. if you have primary key defined in your table, database server doesn't allow you to add same ids for primary key column.

Comment: i guess the primary key is not defined in table and you think it is primary key, am i right? otherwise if id column is defined as primary key, database server doesn't allow same ids in any case.

Answer (score 1):

#### What you are attempting is wrong.

Both the fields have same id and same value as well. You said `id` is your primary key on your table.

> A primary key cannot be duplicated among the rows. <sub>**That is the whole point of having a primary key**</sub>

You mustn't have declared the id field as primary key.

- Remove the bottom row
- Add primary key to the field , run this query

  ```
    ALTER TABLE `tablename` ADD PRIMARY KEY(id) AUTO_INCREMENT
  ```

Now from this point ahead, you will have unique id for all the records you have and you will have no problem on selecting the rows.

Comment: it won't work: select name, id from tab where id in (1, 2, 3); will return just three rows, while the supposed intention of the user is to obtain 1 (in his example) two times according a list with repeated id.

Comment: @ShinTakezou, You guys have already given how to get two rows. I am telling him how the problem should not be created at the first place.

Comment: currently I've not a MySQL to make an actual test; however, I suppose the user inserted the row with an explicit id (and he believed to have inserted "1" two times); what happens when you do so and the primary key has the auto_increment keyword? My memories tell me the auto increment works when you do not explicit the column value (or use special value like null)

Answer (score 1):

try union all

```
(SELECT name,id FROM tblname WHERE id IN (1,2,7,6)) UNION ALL (SELECT name,id FROM tblname WHERE id IN (1))
```

Answer (score 1):

As you say id is  primary key 
you cannot insert duplicate entries for that field
hence the second insert with id 1 might have failed

```
SELECT name,id FROM tblname
```

it will not display the second entry with id 1

because primary key should be unique.

So what your are getting is what you have in Database.

Comment: My point is that the second insert with id 1 should have failed which is different from what sabanUlutas says

Answer (score 1):

**You Try Out This Without Changes In Table**

```
SELECT name,id FROM tblname WHERE id IN (1,2,7,6,1) GROUP BY id
```